# Get Access Token as a Response through Web Portal (OAuth2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

I have implemented a simple system with microservices architecture and in my system, there are around 5 microservice instances and those are working as the resource servers. The communication between the resource server and the authorization server is done with an asymmetric approach by following OAuth password flow.

When the User register or login into the system through the web portal module to call the service at the time I have to return a response which contains email and access_token and the response should be saved in the local storage.

When I call `http://localhost:9098/oauth/token` endpoint then the following error has occurred.

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.
```

**application.yml**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      grant-type: password
      client-id: web
      client-secret: 14292
      access-token-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9098/oauth/token
```

**Config class**

```
@Configuration
public class WebPortalConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.client")
    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oAuthDetails()
    {
        return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate()
    {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuthDetails());
    }
}
```

**OAuthDetails class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class OAuthDetails {

    private String access_token;
    private String token_type;
    private String refresh_token;
    private int expires_in;

}
```

**Service class**

```
private OAuthDetails getOAuthDetails()
    {
        String url="http://127.0.0.1:9098/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nafazbenzema@gmail.com&password=benz";

        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, OAuthDetails.class);
    }
```

P.S -

1. How to overcome this error?
2. is this approach is correct or not, If you have any better way please suggest as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found another approach and some mistakes in my previous code.

**mistake 01**

created bean instance for `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails` but I was using `password flow`.

I will post my answer to get `access_token` with response using `password flow` in `OAUTH2`.

**application.yml**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    access-token-uri: http://localhost:9098/oauth/token
    client-id: web
    client-secret: 14292
    grant-type: password
```

**properties class**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
public class SecurityProperties {


    private OAuth2Properies oauth2;

    public OAuth2Properies getOauth2() {
        return oauth2;
    }

    public void setOauth2(OAuth2Properies oauth2) {
        this.oauth2 = oauth2;
    }

    public static class OAuth2Properies{

        private String accessTokenUri;
        private String clientId;
        private String clientSecret;
        private String grantType;

        public String getAccessTokenUri() {
            return accessTokenUri;
        }

        public void setAccessTokenUri(String accessTokenUri) {
            this.accessTokenUri = accessTokenUri;
        }

        public String getClientId() {
            return clientId;
        }

        public void setClientId(String clientId) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        public String getClientSecret() {
            return clientSecret;
        }

        public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
            this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        }

        public String getGrantType() {
            return grantType;
        }

        public void setGrantType(String grantType) {
            this.grantType = grantType;
        }
    }
}
```

**customeAuthenticationProvider class**

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class Oauth2AuthenticationProvider {

    private SecurityProperties securityProperties;

    public Oauth2AuthenticationProvider(SecurityProperties securityProperties)
    {
        this.securityProperties=securityProperties;
    }

    public OAuth2AccessToken obtainToken(String username, String password) {

        SecurityProperties.OAuth2Properies oAuthDetails=securityProperties.getOauth2();

        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(oAuthDetails.getAccessTokenUri());
        resourceDetails.setClientId(oAuthDetails.getClientId());
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret(oAuthDetails.getClientSecret());
        resourceDetails.setGrantType(oAuthDetails.getGrantType());
        resourceDetails.setUsername(username);
        resourceDetails.setPassword(password);
        DefaultAccessTokenRequest defaultAccessTokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();

        OAuth2AccessToken token;

        try {
            token = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider().obtainAccessToken(resourceDetails, defaultAccessTokenRequest);
        } catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials", accessDeniedException);
        }

        return token;

    }

}
```

**service class**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl{

private String getAccessToken(String userName,String password)
{
authenticationProvider.obtainToken(username,password).toString();

}

}
```